# Parallel updates causing deadlock when no clustered index in where clause column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-deadlocks

We came across a scenario where a deadlock occurs when attempting to update a table from two simultaneous connections twice within the same transaction and its reproducible every time the query is run on 2 query windows in SSMS. (The AccountId column is a non-clustered key)

See below.

[image]

After creating a clustered key on the AccountId column the deadlock doesn't occur anymore. What causes this behavior?

Comment: How many rows are in the table?

Comment: 50,000 records approximately

Comment: presumably there is only one row with `AccountId = 1000?`

Comment: sorry.. i mistook your question, deleted my response, there is exactly one row, but there are 35 columns in a row, that's what i meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a clustered index on AccountId and non clustered index on this column, SQL Server has to lock index key and then row.

So 1st update will be successful and after update you will have only one row locked in the table.
2nd update will try to lock this rows and will be waiting on release of the lock from 1st update. It will be able to obtain key lock on the index.
3rd update will try to lock index key and will be waiting on release of the lock from 2nd update. Deadlock.

I was able to reproduce it using following table:

```
create table test5 (x int,y int)
insert into test5 values (10,15)
GO

insert into test5 values (11,15)
GO 10000

create index ix on test5(x)

select * from test5

begin transaction

update test5
set y = 5
where x = 10

-- wait here

update test5
set y = 5
where x = 10

rollback
```

Comment: I believe there would need to be a certain number of rows in the table for it to escalate to a table lock? I couldn't replicate the problem but I had only one row in my Accounts table so the update just took a row lock

Comment: Still can't replicate it with 200,000 rows :s

Comment: Sorry @Piotr, I am still unable to understand your explanation. Why would the row be still locked after the first update? essentially the update is complete so the lock can be released right?

Comment: Locks on all updated rows are always held till the end of the transaction.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The execution plan has a non clustered index seek outputting the base table RID (`Bmk1000`) and an `UPDATE` operator using a RID lookup. This provides the two resources involved in the deadlock (non clustered index key and the base table row corresponding to the RID).

- Transaction 1 takes the `U` lock on the non-clustered index key for
  AccountId = 1000 then gets a `U` lock on the base table row, converts
  that to an `X` lock and releases the `U` lock on the non clustered index
  key. The `X` lock is held until the end of the transaction.
- Transaction 2 takes the `U` lock on the non-clustered index key for
  AccountId = 1000 but is blocked trying to get the `U` lock on the base
  table row by transaction 1's `X` lock.
- Transaction 1 runs it's second `UPDATE` and tries to get the `U` lock on
  the non-clustered index key for AccountId = 1000. This is already
  held by Transaction 2. Deadlock.